# How to install latest version of git in Redhat 6.x/7.x

Tags: git, redhat

I am trying to install git in Redhat6.
I am following [how to install git](http://tecadmin.net/install-git-2-0-on-centos-rhel-fedora**/) this tutorial.

```
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.0.5.tar.gz
# tar xzf git-2.0.5.tar.gz

# cd git-2.0.5
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
# echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc
# source /etc/bashrc

# git --version
```

I am able to clone the repo and able to download the git zip file. 
but when I execute this command.

```
 make prefix=/usr/local/git all
```

I get this error

```
[varun@home git-2.0.5]# make prefix=/usr/local/git all 
GIT_VERSION =2.0.5
* new build flags
CC credential-store.o /bin/sh: cc: 
command not found make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 127
```

How do I solve this?

I am able to install git using `yum install git`. but by default 1.7.1 is getting install. But i want to install above 2.

**Edit 1**
When I executed

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

It download the required dependency and the above error is gone.

Now when I execute this **`make prefix=/usr/local/git all`** I am getting bellow error

```html
    CC bulk-checkin.o
In file included from cache.h:4,
                 from bulk-checkin.h:7,
                 from bulk-checkin.c:4:
git-compat-util.h:213:25: warning: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:214:25: warning: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:320:25: warning: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:321:26: warning: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:323:28: warning: openssl/x509v3.h: No such file or directory
In file included from bulk-checkin.h:7,
                 from bulk-checkin.c:4:
cache.h:11:21: warning: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
In file included from bulk-checkin.c:5:
csum-file.h:11: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘SHA_CTX’
csum-file.h:23: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘SHA_CTX’
bulk-checkin.c:96: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SHA_CTX’
bulk-checkin.c: In function ‘stream_to_pack’:
bulk-checkin.c:128: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Update’
bulk-checkin.c:128: error: ‘ctx’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bulk-checkin.c:128: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
bulk-checkin.c:128: error: for each function it appears in.)
bulk-checkin.c: In function ‘deflate_to_pack’:
bulk-checkin.c:193: error: ‘SHA_CTX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bulk-checkin.c:193: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ctx’
bulk-checkin.c:205: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Init’
bulk-checkin.c:205: error: ‘ctx’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bulk-checkin.c:222: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘stream_to_pack’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
bulk-checkin.c:95: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘off_t *’
bulk-checkin.c:222: error: incompatible type for argument 6 of ‘stream_to_pack’
bulk-checkin.c:95: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘enum object_type’
bulk-checkin.c:222: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘stream_to_pack’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
bulk-checkin.c:95: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
bulk-checkin.c:222: error: too many arguments to function ‘stream_to_pack’
bulk-checkin.c:237: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Final’
make: *** [bulk-checkin.o] Error 1
```

**`make prefix=/usr/local/git install`** I get this

```html
    CC bulk-checkin.o
In file included from cache.h:4,
                 from bulk-checkin.h:7,
                 from bulk-checkin.c:4:
git-compat-util.h:213:25: warning: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:214:25: warning: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:320:25: warning: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:321:26: warning: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory
git-compat-util.h:323:28: warning: openssl/x509v3.h: No such file or directory
In file included from bulk-checkin.h:7,
                 from bulk-checkin.c:4:
cache.h:11:21: warning: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
In file included from bulk-checkin.c:5:
csum-file.h:11: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘SHA_CTX’
csum-file.h:23: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘SHA_CTX’
bulk-checkin.c:96: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SHA_CTX’
bulk-checkin.c: In function ‘stream_to_pack’:
bulk-checkin.c:128: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Update’
bulk-checkin.c:128: error: ‘ctx’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bulk-checkin.c:128: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
bulk-checkin.c:128: error: for each function it appears in.)
bulk-checkin.c: In function ‘deflate_to_pack’:
bulk-checkin.c:193: error: ‘SHA_CTX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bulk-checkin.c:193: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ctx’
bulk-checkin.c:205: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Init’
bulk-checkin.c:205: error: ‘ctx’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bulk-checkin.c:222: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘stream_to_pack’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
bulk-checkin.c:95: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘off_t *’
bulk-checkin.c:222: error: incompatible type for argument 6 of ‘stream_to_pack’
bulk-checkin.c:95: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘enum object_type’
bulk-checkin.c:222: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘stream_to_pack’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
bulk-checkin.c:95: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
bulk-checkin.c:222: error: too many arguments to function ‘stream_to_pack’
bulk-checkin.c:237: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SHA1_Final’
make: *** [bulk-checkin.o] Error 1
```

And these two line

```
 # echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc
 # source /etc/bashrc
```

are successfully executed

but when I type `git --version` I am still getting

> bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you run config script? Check `echo $CC`

Comment: @hjpotter92 When I run `echo $CC` or `echo $cc` I get a blank line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `/bin/sh: cc: command not found` is the error message and it has been split on 2 lines to add extra confusion. i.e. there is no `cc` command.

It means that you need to install a C compiler. If you run the following command it should install all the necessary tools (gcc, binutils, etc) to compile git.

`yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

You are also missing the necessary development headers, like openssl:

```
yum install openssl-devel curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel zlib-devel
```

Comment: can you please check the above error and any solution for that. cant I download the git folder and set home path in .bash_profile.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below the Steps I followed to install Git without internet access on the system

- Download the desired tarball from below link, on your PC/Laptop https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/. I used the Git-2.8, as the customer requirement was to have version >=2.7.4
- Connect to remote Linux system (via winscp or nay other remote connectivity tool). And Place/Move the downloaded `git-[version].tar.gz` file on desired location on the linux system where you want to install ‘git’. I placed it in Directory: `/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/`
- From the ommand prompt go to the directory where you placed the above file and run below command to untar the package `tar -xvzf git-2.8.0.tar.gz`
- `cd` into the directory that is newly created by the untar command above, e.g. `cd git-2.8.0/`.
- Verify that all the needed files and directories have been uncompressed into the above folder with `ls -ltr`.
- Set the Path and Prefix variables with commands below.

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0/usr/bin
  PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0
  export PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0
  make prefix=/usr/local/git all
  echo $CC
  ```
- Run `./configure` to check the preinstall configuration checks.
- Run `make install` to install.
- Check that `git` has been properly installed with `git --version`.